# How to store date in dd-mon-yyyy format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

The below works for displaying the date, but when writing to the database [in a datetime column] it seems to be getting converted to the default format.

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CONVERT(DATETIME,DATE_FIELD),106),' ','-')
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change the format when it is stored. Make the formatting when show in application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date/time values in the database are stored in a binary format.  They are not stored as strings.  This is the right way to store them.

If you want to fetch the data in a particular format, then use the formula when you retrieve them.  Or, you can add a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add date_field_ddmonyyyy as (REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CONVERT(DATETIME,DATE_FIELD), 106), ' ', '-'));
```